# Error 404. The origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists. Ошибка

Tags: java, spring, jsp, tomcat

Ребята помогите уже все перебробовал, но ничего не работает. Когда ввожу localhost:8080 страница откривается, а когда localhost:8080/page -вилетает Error 404.Помогите сижу уже 4 день.

Вот код RequestMapping:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/page",method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public String showPage(){
      return "file";
    }
```

Comment: Там есть аннотация @ResponseBody или @RestController? По этому куску кода ничего сказать нельзя

Comment: Покажите ваши аннотации класса